# Expand dropdown without changing the container dimensions

Tags: html, css

I have a dropdown box contained inside a div with yellow background. Check plunker [code](http://plnkr.co/edit/whqttI7DAThlmZEtOLKW?p=preview).

When i click on the dropdown button, the drop down expands and the background container too increases in height. It paints the background of dropdown items in yellow.

I have added `z-index` for list items as,

```
<div class="drp-down-cnt" style="z-index:1000;">
```

and it looks like,

[image]

What i expect it to look like,

[image]

Only the drop down button's background must be in yellow whereas the dropdown list items' background must be in white/gray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limit the height of the background container ([plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/NwTnMbPcoqahrGk0netX?p=preview)):

```
.drp-down-bgnd {
   height: 48px;
 }
```

Or change the position to `absolute` so it won't change the container's height ([plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/giIkHXXqCwQEavtMeTDs?p=preview)):

```
.drp-down-cnt{
   position: absolute;
   width: 158px !important;
 }
```